# How does this linked list reverse implementation work?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I am trying to understand how the reverse `LinkedList` code works below...

```
public void reverse(Node<T> h) {
  Node<T> d = new Node<T>();
  Node<T> t;
  while (h.next != null) {
     t = h.next; //temp nodes points to h.next (1st item in list)
     h.next = t.next; //h.next bypasses first node in list.
     t.next = d.next; //t.next points to d.next.. where is d.next pointing to?
     d.next = t; //d.next now points to t.
  }
   h.next = d.next;
  }
```

How does this process work?

A diagram would be amazing. It seems that the nodes from one list are popped off and pushed into a new list? In this case, is `h` pointed to the list being reversed?

Comment: Use a pencil and paper. Make your own diagram. Draw little boxes (or circles or ponies) and link them together with arrows. These arrows represent the "next" field. Then run through the above code by hand moving arrows at each step.

Comment: i am trying but i get confused... d and t are new nodes ?? the main list is h.list correct?

Comment: where are d and t pointing to initially?

Comment: see my comments, but d is assigned but it seems its not pointing anywhere! right?

Comment: thats what i am saying aswell, so t.next=d.next <- points to nowhere.

Comment: Hmmph. Are you *sure* that is working code? My boxes do not seem to agree. I cannot get it to work for a list of 2, 3 or 4. It seems fundamentally flawed it should likely be more like: http://www.mytechinterviews.com/reverse-a-linked-list

Comment: it should work, its from a book.

Comment: `h.next = t.next` seems problematic... as such I'm giving this a +1. What book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to myself, as well as a redaction of the challenge:

The algorithm does work, it is just written in a confusing manner and *doesn't* include the first node (it uses it merely for side-effects), which is a ... questionable design in and of itself.

Rewriting it to avoid the useless `d.next` and scope the `t` better, makes it easier (and possible for me) to follow:

```
public void reverse(Node<T> h) { // draw H under first node
  Node<T> d = null
  while (h.next != null) {
     Node<T> t = h.next;  // draw T under box at end of H arrow (remove any previous T)
     h.next = t.next;     // change arrow from H to end where arrow from box above T ends (no arrow for last element)
     t.next = d;          // draw arrow from box above T to box D is under (no arrow for first element)
     d = t;               // draw D under box (remove any previous D)
   }
   h.next = d;            // draw arrow from H to box D is under
}
```

On to the boxes!

(I would recommend looking at the code at [Reverse a Linked-List](http://www.mytechinterviews.com/reverse-a-linked-list), it is the same concept, but is easier to follow and doesn't have a fake-head node of this implementation.)

---

<del>I know I said "just draw the boxes". So, after a few more of your comments, I drew the boxes. (I pretended I was back in college ;-)</del>

<del>However, **I cannot get it to work either**. I even tried circles.</del>

<del>I suspect the code posted is *not* a working implementation (which is now an open challenge for other people to now prove me wrong; at the very least it may keep this question open ;-)</del>

<del>I have not been able to use it to reverse a list of 2, 3 or 4 elements in length after several attempts (although I have been able to successfully use the [much more intuitive] code presented in [Reverse a Linked-List](http://www.mytechinterviews.com/reverse-a-linked-list)).</del>

<del>I believe there is a flaw in using `h.next` instead of `h` as the "root" node. Perhaps the author is accounting for a `void` return with a dummy-node and side-effect? But in that case the line `h.next = t.next` still seems to break the algorithm.</del>

Comment: +1 for calling out the broken head-node implementation; that's weird.